# loading a custom font from reference library in WP7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fonts

In my app i wanted to use a custom font, i tried below approach to embedded the font into my app. I added font ttf file to the app (into fonts folder) and set build action as content.

And I am using it as,

```
FontFamily font = new FontFamily("/MyWpAppName;Component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#fontname");
```

This is working fine and i can able to use my custom font in my application.

Now, I wanted to externalize this font into a separate library (for various reasons). So I added a new library project to my solution and added my custom font ttf file and set build action as content.

the problem i am having here is i am not able to access this font from my phone application. Some code snippets from my project,

Main wp application,

```
FontFamily font=PhoneClassLibrary.Utils.GetTargetFont();
```

in the PhoneClassLibrary project, Utils.cs file

```
public static FontFamily GetTargetFont()
{
  return FontFamily("/PhoneClassLibrary;Component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#fontName");
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the build action to `Resource` for the font in the other assembly. Setting the build type to `Content` means that the file is not included in the assembly itself, but within the XAP. The line `/PhoneClassLibrary;Component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#fontName` is looking for the fonts inside the assembly itself, which is why it needs to be a `Resource`.

Comment: Clean and rebuild after setting the build type to resource. Also, double-check the actual assembly name because it can be different from the project name.

Comment: made a silly mistake of using incorrect variables...now working fine. Thanks for the help.